# same code, but different display

Tags: php, html

I have make a form in a free host server http://kotsarikos.bugs3.com/calen.html and working properly. Later, i uploaded the same files to my server and i saw this http://www.oedd.gr/supportoedd/calen.html. The two servers has php 5.2! 
What do you think is going wrong??

the code of the form:

```
<form method="POST" action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>'  id="form1">
<fieldset class="fiel">
<legend><b><span class="words">Στοιχεία Παραγγελίας</span></b></legend>
<table border="0">
<tr><td><b><span class="words"> Όνομα: </span></b></td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="fName" id="fName" value="<?php echo $fName;?>"><span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $fNameErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Επώνυμο:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="lName" id="lName" value="<?php echo $lName;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $lNameErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Διεύθυνση:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo $address;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $addressErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Δήμος:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="dimos" id="dimos" value="<?php echo $dimos;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $dimosErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Νομός:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="nomos" id="nomos" value="<?php echo $nomos;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $nomosErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words"> Τ.Κ.:</span> </b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="tk" id="tk" value="<?php echo $tk;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $tkErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Ποσότητα:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="cap" id="cap" value="<?php echo $cap;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $capErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Τηλέφωνο:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="tel" id="tel" value="<?php echo $tel;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $telErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">E-mail:</span></b></td><td> <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"> <span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><span class="words">Παρατηρήσεις:</span></b></td><td> <textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="comments" id="comments" wrap="hard" value="<?php echo $comments;?>"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td id="but"><input type="submit" value="Υποβολή" ></td></tr>
<tr><span class="words">* Πεδία που απαιτούνται</span></tr>

</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

All the html code there is at comment!

Comment: http://kotsarikos.bugs3.com/calen.txt all the html code

Comment: Try to create a minimal reproducible example to isolate the problem.

Comment: http://www.oedd.gr/supportoedd/calen.html gives the 404 Not Found response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not common to parse .html files as php. Just rename your file from calen.html to calen.php so that the php engine can kick in and execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are missing a directive that tell the web server to treat *.html files as php files in your new server.

If you are using apache server, add following in either httpd.conf or in .htaccess files.

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`